# Can't stop .pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py when using a remote interpreter

Tags: python, linux, pycharm

When I end remote debugging using pycharm, there is a processor that can't be terminated.

Here's what I get with the 'ps -aux command':

```
7893  100  0.1 4556260 243028 ?      Rs   Feb02 23307:38 /home/test/.conda/envs/Trajectory/bin/python3.9 /home/test/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client localhost --port 37856 --file /home/test/test_graph.py
```

I tried the command 'kill -9 7893', but I couldn't end it either.

I would like to ask if there is any method other than rebooting it.